# How to determine specific resource responsible for Azure cost?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, resources, azure-storage

```
Azure Portal > Cost Management > Cost Analysis > Cost By Resource > Services
```

provides line-items such as :

```
IP Addresses
IP Addresses - Standard IPv4
Standard IPv4 Static Public IP
Usage
$8.10
```

How to determine the specific resource(s) responsible for these charges ?

Comment: Whoever downvoted please explain why.  I still haven't figured-out how to identify the specific resource(s) responsible for a line-item cost.  I submitted a support request but the support technician doesn't know either.

Answer (score 0):

Tag your resources with appropriate info then it should show up in the billing manager.

At least that is how to do it in AWS, so if that doesn't work in Azure then wait 5 years for Azure to catch up then try again :-)